# Run window onbeforeunload function if form not submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onbeforeunload

I have to run onbeforeunload when form is half filled and visitor try to leave the page, but not when he submit the form. here is my code.

```
tomato = 0; // by default

$('#my_form').submit(function(){
    tomato = 1; // should change when submitted, but its not happening
});

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    if(tomato==0){
        if ($('#business_name').val()) {
            return "Are you sure want abort your listing '"+$('#business_name').val()+"'??";  // Put your custom message here 
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

i hope you guys understood my problem, please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you validate that the form is not entirely filled? And shouldn't it not just be `return true;` instead of `return false;`?

Comment: in the form all fields are required, so the browser itself validates the form. and that function is working fine in the case visitor try to leave page without submitting the form, and first field of the form is filled

Comment: Try and remove the `else { return false; }` bit.

Comment: no use bro... I've already tried that too..

Comment: Are you sure `tomato` is 1 when you try to submit a fully filled in form?

Comment: no its not working, that is why i'm asking the question here...
`return "Are you sure want abort your listing '"+$('#business_name').val()+","+tomato+"'??"; ` i tried this and it says 0 every time... @putvande

Comment: Is your code within `document.ready` statement or after your form in the HTML? If not, try putting at least your `$('#my_form').submit...` within `document.ready`

Comment: all `codes` are in a separate `js` file,  and added before `body` ends. none of them are inside `document.ready`. i'll try that....

Answer (score 0):

`.submit()` triggers a submit event, as in, it submits the form when it is called. you want the `onSubmit` event listener.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
tomato=0; 
$('#my_form').on('submit',function(){
    tomato = 1; 
});
});
```